# Using WebDeploy to deploy database updates

Tags: database, deployment, database-schema, webdeploy

We have adopted WebDeploy for a new project and it seems to handle the deployment of our apps to our Dev and Test servers pretty well.

Now we would like to extend the use of WebDeploy to make it deploy database changes too.

[Scott Gu's blogpost on webdeploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx) states:

> Web Deploy enables you to not only
>   publish files – but also provision
>   database schema/data, run database
>   change scripts, set security ACLs, and
>   more

... but I can't find any good information on how to run database change scripts with 
WebDeploy.

Does anyone have guidance, advice, best-practice or informative links for this?

Thanks

Darren.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2010 Express then you can specify database change scripts in the Package/Publish SQL tab in your project's properties. For more information see the following article:

> [How to: Deploy a Database With a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465343.aspx)